# Suggested way to get all siblings minus self in xml

Tags: xml, xpath

To get all following siblings, I can do:

```
node/following-sibling::*
```

And to get all preceding siblings, I can do:

```
node/previous-sibling::*
```

And to get all siblings, including the current node, I can do:

```
node/parent::*/child::*
```

What is the suggested way to get all siblings except self? Here's an example input and what I'm currently using:

```
    <platformLocks>
      <platformLock territory="US" lock="true"/>
      <platformLock territory="CA" lock="true"/>
      <platformLock territory="FR" lock="true"/>
    </platformLocks>

<!-- assume current node is the middle one -->
descendant::platformLock[position()=2]/following-sibling::*|
descendant::platformLock[position()=2]/preceding-sibling::*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath questions, you really need to say which version of XPath. XPath 2.0 and 3.1 are so much more powerful, but many people are stuck on 1.0.

In XPath 2.0+ the simplest is probably `../* except .`.

In 1.0, the simplest is probably to form the union of preceding and following siblings: `preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*`.

Comment: what would be the most compact way to do: `preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*`. Can my approach be simplified from what is there in the question?

Comment: ah, just from trial-and-error it looks like you can use parens to do a condition within a step: `platformLocks/platformLock[2]/(following-sibling::*|preceding-sibling::*)` -- never knew that!